# Convertir cadena SUBTSR de mayúscula a minúscula

Tags: sql, oracle

Quiero saber como puedo convertir de mayúsculas a minúsculas cierta cadena que extraigo haciendo uso de un **SUBSTR** en **SQL**, solo deseo convertir la primera letra de cada palabra separada por un espacio.

El query que estoy utilizando para extraer la cadena es el siguiente:

```
(SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(TEXT, 'pruebaExtraer="([^"]+)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
        FROM COMMENT
        WHERE ID = ID
        AND CODE = '10') EXTRACCIÓN,
```

Lo que contiene la cadena es lo siguiente:

- PRUEBA PARA EXTRAER

**NOTA:**

Quiero convertir la primera letra en mayúscula de lo que obtenga en la cadena, debería quedar algo así:

- Prueba Para Extraer

Hay que tener en cuenta que el tamaño de la cadena puede cambiar ya que se estará haciendo uso en otras funcionalidades.

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Se intento con la función `LOWERCASE` pero esta me convierte toda la cadena a minúscula.

Comment: Realmente da igual de dónde venga la cadena, si de un SUBSTR o una concatenación o directamente de un campo. Así que lo que tienes que buscar es "Convertir cadena de mayúscula a minúscula".

Comment: @SJuan76 gracias por tu comentario, puedes agregar por favor un ejemplo como respuesta para darle validez.

Comment: Google "oracle convertir de mayúscula a minúscula"

Comment: @SJuan76 Al realizar la búsqueda que me solicitaste me arroja ejemplos con la función `LOWERCASE` y esto me convierte en minúscula toda la cadena, por favor leer **NOTA** en la pregunta.

Comment: Separa la cadena en subcadenas (una subcadena para la primera letra, otra para las siguientes), y en cada subcadena aplicas lowercase o no según toque, y luego vuelves a concatenar.

Comment: @SJuan76 Investigando un poco mas, estuve consultando la función `INITCAP` que me dices sobre esta función, se puede usar en este caso ?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una función para realizar la tarea de analizar cada cadena y devolver la combinación correcta de mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Por ejemplo, he adaptado la función publicada en [esta excelente respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/230177/255257) a una pregunta similar en StackOverflow en inglés, quedando así:

```
create function ProperCase(@Texto as varchar(8000))
returns varchar(8000)
as
begin
  declare @Reset bit;
  declare @Resultado varchar(8000);
  declare @i int;
  declare @c char(1);

  if @Texto is null
    return null;

  select @Reset = 1, @i = 1, @Resultado = '';

  while (@i <= len(@Texto))
    select @c = substring(@Texto, @i, 1),
      @Resultado = @Resultado + case when @Reset = 1 then UPPER(@c) else LOWER(@c) end,
      @Reset = case when @c like '[a-zA-Z]' then 0 else 1 end,
      @i = @i + 1
  return @Resultado
end
```

Su uso sería como este:

```
select dbo.ProperCase('HOLA COMO ESTÁS, ESPERO QUE BIEN y que me llames mañana por la mañana');
```

Lo que devuelve:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hola Como Estás, Espero Que Bien Y Que Me Llames Mañana Por La Mañana

(1 row affected)


Completion time: 2020-09-15T17:24:36.3538071-06:00
```

Obviamente, puede ser utilizada con cualquier campo de tipo varchar, por ejemplo:

```
select Empleado.Id, dbo.ProperCase(empleado.NombreCompleto) NombreProper
  from Empleado;
```